# I have problem with result of Apache Ignite when turned on QueryParallelism

Tags: java, ignite

When I turned on QueryParallelism with '8' count of thread and executed my SQL.

```
SELECT ASSET_CLASS FROM BASEENTITY GROUP BY ASSET_CLASS.
```

I got 8 rows of results.

```
ASSET_CLASS:
Stocks
Stocks
Stocks
Stocks
Stocks
Stocks
Stocks
Stocks
```

If I turn on 4 thread, then I got 4 rows, but for SQL Logic I had to got 1 row.
What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think QueryParallelism assumes that you do GROUP BY on affinity column. If it's not, then duplicate results will be caused by grouping.

(`collocated=true` does the same btw)

Comment: collocated=true doesn't help

Comment: Can I make affinity column for several columns?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it won't help: you will now need to always `GROUP BY` all of affinity columns.

Comment: Thanks for helping. How to set affinity_key for several columns? By  Documentation, I can set only one affinity_key during creating table

Comment: I think you can put both of fields into a separate class and put `@AffinityKeyMapped` on field of that class. Not sure if it works, and certainly not sure if you can do that with `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5795 - now SQL ignores for @AffinityKeyMapped  at all.